Django template does not inherit tag from parent
I would like to get a clarification of the following.
Is it necessary to add the {% load static %} tag on every child template in my project?

So far I have not been able to get my child templates to inherit this tag from their parents. However, the book I read states the following "We need to add the static files to our templates by adding {% load static %} to the top of base.html. Because our other templates inherit from base.html, we only have to add this once."

This appears not be true from my experience.
thanks for you help.

Can you explain where you read this?


Is it necessary to add the {% load static %} tag on every child template in my project?

Yes, this is a bit similar to importing modules. In Python if you import a module A, and module A imports a module B; then that does not mean the items of that module B are in scope of module A.
The {% load … %} template tag [Django-doc] will thus load the template tags in the scope of that specific template, not all templates that inherit from it.
If you really want this, you can however add the template tags to the builtins option [Django-doc] of the template engine, so:
# settings.py

# …

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {'builtins': ['my_app.templatetags.my_module']},
    },
]
This will then look as if you loaded {% load my_module %} in every template.

Of course but if you don't want to add it en each template, add it only in your base.html template. i recommand you the second option for to make your code lite.

Adding only to my base (parent) template is not working for me. That is what I stated in the question.
